# Bijective continuous map to compact: Is the source compact?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be bijective continuous and $Y$ is compact (my $X$ and $Y$ are also Hausdorff.)

> Is X necessarily compact?

If not, what can be a $\textit{weak}$ extra condition so that this is true?

---

My motivation:

Assume that for a $\textit{free}$ group action $\rho:X\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow X$ the graph $\Gamma$ of the map

$\gamma:X\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow X\times X,~~~(x,g)\mapsto (x,\rho(x,g))$

is $\textit{closed}$.

I want to show that this action is locally proper (i.e. any point of $X$ has a compact $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$-stable neighborhood to which the restriction of $\rho$ is proper.)

Proof: It suffices to show that, for any $x\in X$ and a compact neighborhood $X\supseteq K_x\ni x$ of $x$, the restriction map $\rho|_{{K_x}\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})}$ is proper. One has

$Im\left(\gamma|_{{K_x}\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})}\right)=\Gamma\cap({K_x}\times X).$

Since the action $\rho$ is free, the map

$\gamma|_{{K_x}\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})}: K_x\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})
\longrightarrow \Gamma\cap({K_x}\times X)$

is injective (and thus bijective.)

For a compact $K\subset X$, we want the set

$\left(\rho|_{{K_x}\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})}\right)^{-1}(K)=\left(\gamma|_{{K_x}\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})}\right)^{-1}\left(\Gamma\cap({K_x}\times K)\right)$

to be compact. This would follow from the statement I ask, since $\Gamma\subset X\times X$ is closed.

Comment: What do you mean by a "stable neighborhood"? Do you mean "invariant" (this would be impossible)? It seems that for a locally compact $X$ you are asking for existence of a neighborhood $U$ of any given $x\in X$ such that $\{g\in G: gU\cap U\ne\emptyset\}$ is relatively compact in $G$. If so, you should state this clearly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks. I'll correct this question later today.

Comment: Also: Do you mean that then graph of the map is closed or the map itself (which is a standard requirement in the theory of proper actions)?

Comment: I mean the image of $\gamma$ is closed. By the way, I have found a proof for the local properness I want. Since the action is free, $\gamma$ is a local embedding. Since the image of $\gamma$ is closed, local properness follows.

Answer (score 2):

No, one could have any compact Hausdorff space for $Y$ and then take $X$ to be the same space with the discrete topology (and $f$ to be the identity map).

Comment: Actually my $X$ is a product of Grassmanians so can we please exclude pathological cases? Thanks.

Comment: Well, how about $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1$ via $f(t)=e^{it}$?

Comment: Thanks. Let me think of a way to modify my question to capture the issue I'm having (please read the motivation part if you have time.)